# Select other table as a column based on datetime in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables which has a relationship, but I want to grouping them based on time. Here are the tables

[image]
[image]
I want select a receipt as a column based on `published_at`, it must be in between `pickup_time` and `drop_time`, so will get this result :

[image]
I tried with `JOIN`, but it seems like select rows with `drop_time` is `NULL` only

```
SELECT 
  t.source_id AS source_id, 
  t.pickup_time AS pickup_time,
  t.drop_time AS drop_time,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(r.source_id, r.receipt_id, r.published_at) ORDER BY r.published_at LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS receipt
FROM `my-project-gcp.data_source.trips` AS t
JOIN `my-project-gcp.data_source.receipts` AS r
ON
  t.source_id = r.source_id
  AND
  r.published_at >= t.pickup_time
  AND (
    r.published_at <= t.drop_time
    OR t.drop_time IS NULL
  )
GROUP BY source_id, pickup_time, drop_time
```

and tried with sub-query, got

```
Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN
```

```
SELECT 
t.source_id AS source_id, 
t.pickup_time AS pickup_time,
t.drop_time AS drop_time, 
ARRAY_AGG((
  SELECT 
  STRUCT(r.source_id, r.receipt_id, r.published_at)
  FROM `my-project-gcp.data_source.receipts` as r
  WHERE
  t.source_id = r.source_id
  AND
  r.published_at >= t.pickup_time
  AND (
    r.published_at <= t.drop_time
    OR t.drop_time IS NULL
  )
  LIMIT 1
))[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS receipt
FROM `my-project-gcp.data_source.trips` as t
GROUP BY source_id, pickup_time, drop_time
```

Comment: In your sample, why receipt_id 56241 is linked to DOE driver and isn't linked to FOO driver? His **published_at** time can be matched with both.

Comment: @MaxZolotenko receipt_id `56241`has published_at `2022-07-19T13:04:21` which that time linked to `doe` as driver on the period pickup_time `2022-07-19T12:00:01` - drop_time `2022-07-19T13:05:11`, while`foo` has pickup_time `2022-07-19T14:30:00`

Comment: Hi @itx, are you still facing the issue?

Comment: Hi @ShipraSarkar the problem was solved on my another post

Comment: Hi @itx , Can you post the answer here? And if you  are still looking for the solution or workaround for this issue, let me know.

Comment: @ShipraSarkar yes it is

Answer (score 1):

Each `source_id` is a car and only one driver can drive a car at once.
We can partition therefore by that entry.

Your approach is working for small tables. Since there is no unique join key, the cross join fails on large tables.

I present here a solution with `union all` and look back technique. This is quite fast and works with up to middle large table sizes in the range of a few GB. It prevents the cross join, but is a quite long script.

In the table `trips` are all drives by the drivers are listed. The `receipts` list all `fines`.
We need a unique row identication of each trip to join on this one later on. We use the row number for this, please see table `trips_with_rowid`.

The table `summery_tmp` unions three tables. First we load the `trips` table and add an empty column for the `fines`. Then we load the `trips` table again to mark the times were no one was driving the car. Finally, we add the table `receipts` such that only the columns `source_id`, `pickup_time` and fine is filled.
This table is sorted by the `pickup_time` for each `source_id` and the table `summary`. So the fine entries are under the entry of the driver getting the car. The column `row_id_new` is filled for the fine entries by the value of the `row_id` of the driver getting the car.

Grouping by `row_id_new` and filtering unneeded entries does the job.
I changed the second of the entered times (lazyness), thus it differs a bit from your result.

```
With trips as
(Select 1 source_id ,timestamp("2022-7-19 9:37:47") pickup_time, timestamp("2022-07-19 9:40:00") as drop_time, "jhon" driver_name
Union all Select 1 ,timestamp("2022-7-19 12:00:01"),timestamp("2022-7-19 13:05:11"),"doe"
Union all Select 1 ,timestamp("2022-7-19 14:30:01"),null,"foo"
Union all Select 3 ,timestamp("2022-7-24 08:35:01"),timestamp("2022-7-24 09:15:01"),"bar"
Union all Select 4 ,timestamp("2022-7-25 10:24:01"),timestamp("2022-7-25 11:14:01"),"jhon"
),
receipts as 
(Select 1 source_id, 101 receipt_id, timestamp("2022-07-19 9:37:47") published_at,40 price
Union all Select 1,102, timestamp("2022-07-19 13:04:47"),45
Union all Select 1,103, timestamp("2022-07-19 15:23:00"),32
Union all Select 3,301, timestamp("2022-07-24 09:15:47"),45
Union all Select 4,401, timestamp("2022-07-25 11:13:47"),45
Union all Select 5,501, timestamp("2022-07-18 07:12:47"),45
),
trips_with_rowid as 
(
  SELECT 2*row_number() over (order by source_id,pickup_time) as row_id, * from trips
),
summery_tmp as 
(
Select *, null as fines from trips_with_rowid
union all Select row_id+1,source_id,drop_time,null,concat("no driver, last one ",driver_name),null  from trips_with_rowid
union all select null,source_id, published_at, null,null, R from receipts R
),
summery as 
(
  SELECT last_value(row_id ignore nulls) over (partition by source_id order by pickup_time ) row_id_new
  ,* 
  
  from summery_tmp
  order by 1,2
)
select source_id,min(pickup_time) pickup_time, min(drop_time) drop_time,
any_value(driver_name) driver_name, array_agg(fines IGNORE NULLS)  as fines_Sum
 from summery
 group by row_id_new,source_id

 having fines_sum is not null or (pickup_time is not null and driver_name not like "no driver%")
  order by 1,2
```

Comment: Actually source_id `3` is has receipt by the way, the receipt still on the range of the trip. Definitely for the last one is an update row for a receipt whose already has a driver on july 18th, the query should be in range of date (update) both trips and receipts, that's why I got a receipt without a driver. I have made a mistake on OP, the `source_id` shouldn't be newer (not `5`) for it. A/w thank you looks good for that long query, I will learn it first.

Comment: Hi @Samuel I got another case, if source_id `4` and has drop_time `null` it will broke the result